# how to write an XSLT that counts the rows in a table?

Tags: xml, xquery

I have this XML and I want to check how  many rows are in the XML file.

Where do I write the query? Can I write it in the XSLT file, if yes, how to make it?

XML file

```
<catalog>
  <cd>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
  </cd>
  <cd>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
  </cd>
</catalog>
```

XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="/">
<html> 
<body>
  <h2>My CD Collection</h2>
  <table border="1">
    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
      <th style="text-align:left">Title</th>
      <th style="text-align:left">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <xsl:for-each select="catalog/cd">
    <tr>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="title"/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="artist"/></td>
    </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count how many `<cd>` elements there are in the input XML with the [`count()` function](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-count):

```
count(/catalog/cd)
```

You didn't indicate where you wanted that count to appear. Assuming that you wanted to display the count in the heading:

```
<h2>My CD Collection (<xsl:value-of select="count(/catalog/cd)"/>)</h2>
```

Comment: thank you so much, Im sorry that I cant rate you.

Comment: I hava one more question, If I have In the table also dade and I need to check for evrey date If it more than two years from today? do u have any idia how to check it? Thank you so much! @mandhansen

Comment: There are a number of dateTime functions available, if you can use XSLT 2.0 https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#dates-times. But it's probably best to ask a separate question (with enough info about the source data and problem that you are trying to solve)

Comment: ok thanks! for this question do you know if there is a way to count the rows in js or xquery?

Comment: XQuery has the same XPath functions available, so count() will work the same. For JavaScript, it’s possible but you would want that in the HTML page. Again, post as a question with enough detail explaining what you are trying to accomplish.